# Is creating a table with a "_" the same thing as creating a table without a "_"?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am used to creating a table in SQL like this:

```
String createItems = "CREATE TABLE items(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ...)
```

...but in a video I was watching the tutor created a table like this with a "_":

```
String createItems = "CREATE TABLE items(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ...)
```

**Is this the same thing, or is there any difference?**
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention of `_id` primary key naming comes from [`CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter) that requires a column with such name in the cursor (not necessarily in the table).

Other than that, it is just an identifier for a column.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So in the case that we didn't have a "_" and we queried to the cursor something like: String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC" and then said Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(myQuery, null), would we get an error? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, never mind. In that case we aren't trying to put data from a Cursor into a ListView using CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

you think the wrong is in `_id` ?
this is a just column name you name it as you like

Comment: No, why do you need the "_"; I know you can name columns as you like.

Comment: It's not needed. It's a prefix the guy from the video used, nothing else. You are following a tutorial, you take the idea of it, not word per word.

Comment: Ok, I am just curious. Thanks.